# Virus was found in my python program after recompiling into exe?

Tags: auto-py-to-exe

I received a message from windows defender, saying, that my pc is infected with Trojan:Win32/Wacatac.B!ml virus. But worst of all, this virus was found in my python script. C:\Users\USER\Downloads\My Diary 6\My_Diary_6.exe - this is my program, which was written in python, then recompiled into exe. https://github.com/Anonymous6598/Anonymous6598/tree/My-family/My%20Diary%206 - this is link to my github repository. I don't know what happend. Maybe it's a bug. Has someone had this problem?

In panic i deleted .exe file, but understood that it was my app...

Answer (score 1):

Your program was not infected with a trojan, nor is there anything wrong with it. Windows defender and several other third party antivirus tools flag most if not all programs compiled with pyinstaller as false positives. The same is true for many tools that convert python programs into executable files.

you can read more about it from the following links

https://medium.com/@markhank/how-to-stop-your-python-programs-being-seen-as-malware-bfd7eb407a7

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5854#issuecomment-846312429

You can submit your executables to be analyzed by microsoft for them to be whitelisted at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/filesubmission  This process usually takes a day or two in my experience.

Comment: What antivirus do you prefer for developers?

Comment: @anonymous6598  I wouldn't recommend one in the first place.

Comment: Maybe it was caused by pickle serializer